# Tool for visualisation data manipulation by microservices

Tags: data-visualization, diagram, uml, dataflow

I have the following use case, implemented with microservices connected with kafka messages:

Over a webhook (microservice 1), I retrieve actual information about the state of some local installed devices. The model is designed for example like this:

```
{
    'device': 'ApplianceX',
    'propertyAddress': 4711,
    'propertyName': 'Long Unreadable Name',
    'propertyValue': 'Value in byte array and crazy format'
     ... more metadata
}
```

The data will be produced to a topic. A `Parser` consumes the topic and convert the message to a message in a conform format (It is also possible, that the parser consumes 1 message and produces more than 1 - it depends on the value!).

The third step is, that several microservices consumes the the topic, where the `Parser` is producing and updates only specific properties of their target data model. The flow looks like this:

```
                                                                  Target model 1
                                                            +--------->Property A
                                  +------------->  Service A+          Property B
                                  |                                    Property C
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
       Data  +-----------> Parser +
                                  |                               Target model 2
                                  |                         +--------->Property A
                                  +--------------> Service B+--------->Property D
                                  |                                    Property Y
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |                                      ...
                                  |
                                  +--------------> Service C
```

Now to my question:

I hope you can imagine my need. What is the best tool, to visualize this construct?

As Actor I want to see by an input of the property address the lifecycle of the value and in which property of the services the value results.